# WordPress back-end cannot be accessed. Blank page comes up

Tags: php, wordpress, security, server, code-injection

My wordpress site's backend cannot be accessed and when I try to go to `wp-admin` page, it only shows a blank page.

And when I check via the file manager, I discovered some unusual code has been generated on the top of some of the Wordpress and Theme files (`wp-cofing.php, header.php, footer.php ..etc.`)

Here's an screenshot of my `wp-config.php` file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/otk1xq2i7t6yojr/Untitled.png?dl=0

So, what is this ? Never experienced such thing in my life...

How to get my site back ? All the sites on that server has been affected...

Comment: You've been hacked. That's a huge `base64_encoded` string that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Yeah, I also thought so... So, what to do to get it back ?

Comment: Hacking quesitons are off topic. Carefully follow https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Comment: Dude, I'm not asking "how to hack". I'm asking "how to recover..". How could that be off topic ? Why there's a tag called "Security" ?

Comment: The reason there is a tag called "security" is so people can ask questions about how to write software that is resistant (or outright impervious) to exploitation. Sadly, most wordpress plugin developers don't bother learning about security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odds are, that malicious string is the same in all the affected files. Remove them all manually ( search + replace across the entire installation folder ).

That should get admin side running.

Then install a security plugin ( e.g. WordFence ) to scan the installation for any other suspicious code.

Then change your passwords and hashes in the config file.

Comment: Well, that's an answer!!! :) Thanks!!!